# Bokeh ValueError: expected an element of either Seq(String)

Tags: python-3.x, bokeh, valueerror

I'm trying to build a simple bar chart via bokeh but struggling for it to recognize the x-axis and keep getting a ValueError... I think it needs to be in string format but for some reason whatever I try it just won't work. Please note, the column that contains the Years (as floats by the looks of it) is called RegionName, if it seems confusing. Please see my code below, any suggestions?

```
import pandas as pd
from bokeh.plotting import figure, output_file, show
from bokeh.models import ColumnDataSource
from bokeh.models.tools import HoverTool
import os
from bokeh.palettes import Spectral5
from bokeh.transform import factor_cmap

os.chdir("C:/Users/Vladimir.Tikhnenko/Python/Land Reg")

# Pivot data

def pivot2(infile="Land Registry.csv", outfile="SalesVolume.csv"):
    df=pd.read_csv(infile)
    table=pd.pivot_table(df,index= 
    ["RegionName"],columns="Year",values="SalesVolume",aggfunc=sum)
    table.to_csv(outfile)
    return table
pivot2()

# Transpose data 

df=pd.read_csv("SalesVolume.csv")
df=df.drop(df.columns[1:28],1)
df=pd.read_csv("SalesVolume.csv", index_col=0, header=None).T
df.to_csv("C:\\Users\Vladimir.Tikhnenko\Python\Land 
Reg\SalesVolume.csv",index=None)

df=pd.read_csv("SalesVolume.csv")
source = ColumnDataSource(df)
years = source.data['RegionName'].tolist()
p = figure(x_range=['RegionName'])

color_map = factor_cmap(field_name='RegionName',palette=Spectral5, 
factors=years)

p.vbar(x='RegionName', top='Southwark', source=source, width=1, 
color=color_map)

p.title.text ='Transactions'
p.xaxis.axis_label = 'Years'
p.yaxis.axis_label = 'Number of Sales'

show(p)
```

the error message is

```
ValueError: expected an element of either Seq(String), Seq(Tuple(String, 
String)) or Seq(Tuple(String, String, String)), got [1968.0, 1969.0, 1970.0, 
1971.0, 1972.0, 1973.0, 1974.0, 1975.0, 1976.0, 1977.0, 1978.0, 1979.0, 
1980.0, 1981.0, 1982.0, 1983.0, 1984.0, 1985.0, 1986.0, 1987.0, 1988.0, 
1989.0, 1990.0, 1991.0, 1992.0, 1993.0, 1994.0, 1995.0, 1996.0, 1997.0, 
1998.0, 1999.0, 2000.0, 2001.0, 2002.0, 2003.0, 2004.0, 2005.0, 2006.0, 
2007.0, 2008.0, 2009.0, 2010.0, 2011.0, 2012.0, 2013.0, 2014.0, 2015.0, 
2016.0, 2017.0, 2018.0]
```

Comment: Can't test your code easily without the input file but what happens if you replace the elements of `years` with strings, using `string_years = [str(year) for year in years]
` and then put `factors=string_years`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Categorical factors must only be strings (or sequences of strings for nested factors), so `factor_cmap` only accepts lists of those things. You passed it a list a numbers, which causes the error shown. To use use the years as categorical factors, you need to convert them to strings as suggested, and use those string values to initialize `x_range`, and for the coordinates to `vbar`.

Alternatively, if you want to use numerical values for the years, but just want to have fixed, controlled tick locations, do this:

```
p = figure() # don't pass x_range
p.xaxis.ticker = years
```

And then also use `linear_cmap` to map the numerical values (instead of `factor_cmap`)